# The continuity of $L^2$ gradient on moving domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-optimization, sobolev-spaces

Let $I:=(0,1)$ be given. Let $\bar u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ be given. Define the energy functional, where $x\in I$ is fixed,
$$
T(u,x):=\int_{I\setminus \{x\}}|u'|^2dx+\int_I|u-\bar u|^2dx,\text{ for }u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\})
$$
and the function $t$: $I\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
t(x):=\inf\{ T(u,x):\,\,u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\}\}
$$
Hence, $t(x)$ is well defined.

My question: do we have $t(x)$ is continuous? If yes, what the minimum assumption we need to put on $\bar u$. So far I give $\bar u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$, but it would be ideal that $\bar u\in BV(I)$.

Moreover, I am also wondering that if I define 
$$
u_x:=\operatorname{argmin}\{ T(u,x):\,\,u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\}\}
$$
Then do I have $u_x$ is continuous in $L^1$ sense? i.e., if $x\to x_0$, then $u_x\to u_{x_0}$ in $L^1$.

Thank you!